# Can we conclude this from ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

Assume that sets exist for a given property. Then can we derive from ZFC that there exists a set containing all those (existing) sets?

Comment: [Famously, no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

Comment: As an aside, the definitive "no" answer to your question can be taken as motivation for the [axiom schema of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), which says that if you fix a set $A$ then there *does* exist a subset $B$ consisting of all elements satisfying your given property.

Comment: Compare that to the discussion of [unrestricted comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension) on the same wikipedia page, which is what you are asking about.

Comment: Only with a further restriction, such as its being a property of the form "$x$ has property $P$, and is of rank $\le\alpha$".

Comment: Didn't we say something about descriptive titles?

Answer (score 4):

No. In particular, in ZFC, there is no set of all sets (which would be equivalent to the set of all sets $x$ which satisfy the property $x = x$).

The proof is the famous *Russell's paradox*. We will prove, by contradiction, that there is no set which contains all sets. Start by assuming that $V$ is the set of all sets. Now, using the axiom of specification, define the set

$$P = \{x : x \in V, x \notin x\}.$$

Is $P$ an element of $P$? By definition, $P$ is in $P$ if and only if $P$ is in $V$ but $P$ is not in $P$. But since all sets are in $V$, we can simply say: $P$ is in $P$ if and only if $P$ is not in $P$. But that's impossible.

So, we have proven, by contradiction, that there is no set which contains itself.

Comment: Or, more directly, there is no set of sets which satisfy the property $Q(x) : x \notin x$.